# Loss increases after 4000 Epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to train a RNN Network for stock price prediction for my Master Thesis. I have additional input values (6), not just the stock prices by itself.

Using an LSTM Network with the "optimal" structure based on Hyperparameter Tuning with Keras Tuner, i observed a significant increase in the losses for training and validation in my case after 4000 Epochs.

My dataset consists of about 12 000 datapoints and i use the `Adam` optimizer with `mean_absolute_error` loss function

The Network is quite deep with the following layers:

LSTM (24 unit)
Dropout
LSTM (366 unit)
Dropout
LSTM (150 unit)
Dropout
Dense (1 unit)

I attached a graph of the loss (sorry for the german)

I would really like to understand what leads to this (for me) unexpected behaviour.

[image: Loss development]

Comment: Pretty hard to tell from this, but here are some things to take a look at. 1. I don't trust that your loss is near zero in the beginning. Are you sure you're calculating loss correctly? 2. How large is your validation set? 3. It seems like the first ~2000 epochs are all good, have you tried re-running with 2k epochs and testing your model after that? 3. Why are you using dropout on a single neuron in the end?

Comment: Sorry, i reedited the question, the dense layer with 1 neuron is the last

Comment: 'The Validation set ist about 5k sets. The Loss i use the build in calculation from keras

Answer (score 0):

Your learning rate (often called alpha) is probably too large. Try to factor the learning rate down and try again.

Comment: So far i used the default alpha, i will try a lower value as soon as my PC is done with another hyperparameter training. takes probably another 12 hours ;)

Comment: Does lowering the learning rate actually help or does it just delay the effect seen with the default alpha?

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of overfitting to the training data. if your setup for training uses a validation set for computing the accuracy, after a number of epochs the model becomes overfit on the training data which means it does very well on the training data but it won't generalize well on verification and test data. to solve this issue you could use regularization techniques or the easier approach is to just stop training when the accuracy starts to drop.

Comment: I would have expected Overfitting to show as increases loss on validation data, but not on training data. And in my case i see increased losses in Validation and Training data.
The blue is the LSTM Training data loss and the red is the LSTM Validation data loss.